# Can I create a report using Crystal Report which behaves like DataGridView .NET?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, datagridview, crystal-reports

I am trying to create a Crystal Report in which I need hide columns like DataGridView.

I have a DataGridView which has columns as follows

*|Sales Order|Supplier|Product Name|Product Type|Quantity|Order Price|Mode of Payment|Order Status|Order Status|Order Date|Total Amount|*

I have a Filter Button that will Filter the Columns of the DataGridView.
I only set the DataGridView as follows
`Datagridview1.Columns(ColumntoHide).Visible = False`

I want my report to appear same as DataGridView when i Filtered the Columns.

```
Sub SalesOrder()
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor

    With dt
        .Columns.Add("salesorder")
        .Columns.Add("supplier")
        .Columns.Add("prodname")
        .Columns.Add("prodtype")
        .Columns.Add("qty")
        .Columns.Add("orderprice")
        .Columns.Add("payment")
        .Columns.Add("orderstatus")
        .Columns.Add("orderdate")
        .Columns.Add("total")
        .Columns.Add("overall")
    End With

    For Each dr As DataGridViewRow In frmSalesOrderReport.dgvRSalesOrder.Rows
        dt.Rows.Add(dr.Cells(1).Value, dr.Cells(2).Value, dr.Cells(3).Value, dr.Cells(4).Value, dr.Cells(5).Value, dr.Cells(6).Value, dr.Cells(7).Value, dr.Cells(8).Value, CDate(dr.Cells(9).Value).ToString("MMM dd, yy"), dr.Cells(10).Value, frmSalesOrderReport.txtTotal.Text)
    Next

    Dim rptDoc As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument

    rptDoc = New crSalesOrder
    rptDoc.SetDataSource(dt)
    frmReports.crvReports.ReportSource = rptDoc

    frmReports.ShowDialog()
    frmReports.Dispose()

    Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default
End Sub
```

This is how I am trying to achieve what I want in my Current Report but it's Drag and Drop Method so even if I filtered the Columns the Columns in the Report will be not automatically hiding. Also I Used Box Object and Line Object to Create my table.

Comment: When you loop through the rows in your DataGridView are the rows that are not displayed due to your filters being included in your DataTable `dt`?  Is that the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Yes, it is included in my `dt` , no . my problem is i want the Report to be filtered also when i filtered the Datagridview.

Comment: I'm not sure if Crystal can dynamically redraw a report as filters in your GridView change.  I believe that will require a hook to the appropriate Event Handler that simply discards the previously rendered report and then rebuilds the report with a new dataset, building the dataset based upon the new filters.  At least that is how I would imagine it working.  It might help to add the Visual Basic tag to this and get some input from a more experience VB developer than myself.

Comment: Why not simply check if the column is hidden before adding it to the DataTable?